# Can I enter Romania with a Polish Temporary Residence Card?

Tags: schengen-visas, poland, romania, long-stay-visas

I am having a problem getting a Romanian visa, and my Student Mobility starts very soon. Neither the system on the website of the Romanian e-visa nor the local embassy in Warsaw responds to me. When I call them, they hang up, after asking me if I speak Romanian. Is there any possibility to enter Romania from inside of Schengen zone with a Polish Temporary Residence Card, and legally apply for residence inside Romania?

I was looking for such information everywhere, but it seems like my case is very special. My citizenship doesn't really matters; it's a third world country and I need a visa to enter literally everywhere.

Comment: Why do you say that your citizenship doesn't matter? It is the most important fact. Polish documents are for Poland. Note: Schengen visa is "Schengen" not Polish visa. Schengen and EU gives some right to own citizen, not to other citizen (in fact you may not be allowed to go outside a country (also if such country is in Schengen) in some cases.

Comment: My country barely has any diplomatic relationships with both Romania and Poland. So my citizenship is just a not-important, but recognized, third-world country.

Answer (score 0):

You may use your temporary residence permit (see https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040), but you risk to misuse it. The residence permit probably come with some obligation. For sure it doesn't allow you to use it to reside elsewhere in EU, but it allow you to travel in Romania.

So, you should be able to enter into Romania (under some conditions) and stay there (also with some conditions) but not more than the validity of the Polish permit. You should carefully check not to have more troubles (and a ban) (either in Poland or in Romania). You may need to read carefully the linked site and relative documents, there are many rules so you should check what apply to you.

Personally, I would have some doubt about you want to study in Romania, but you do no understand the local language. I think this could raise questions for your study permit.